# How to choose a list of

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

have used the 2to3 python 2.7 inbuilt library to convert python 2.7 to latest. I am seeing there are .bak files created in the project for every file.

Comment: Have you created a class that implements DbContext? Do you have models representing these tables? If you you have a long way to go before we can help you write an EF query.

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't posted your models or context, I am going to assume that you have POCOs that match the schema in the picture with appropriate navigation properties defined. I will use `context` in place of your dbContext.

```
var followersList = context.ShipFollowers.Where(
    shipFollower => !shipFollower.Ship.Outcomes.Any(
        outcome => outcome.Battles.Any(
            battle => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(battle.Date) == DateTime.Today)))
    .Select(shipFollower => shipFollower.Follower).ToList();
```

This will query the ShipFollowers with ships that don't have any outcomes with battles that have date's matching today. Then, it will select the Followers from the ShipFollowers.

Comment: Make sure you have using System.Data.Entity; statement in your file